# I need some help removing part of filename on my mac directory with terminal utility

Tags: macos, filenames

I'd like to remove this part of the filenames '225086191.sd.mp4' from the filenames looking like this:

> '225086191.sd.mp4 11juillet2017.mp4' 
>   '221896766.sd.mp4 16juin2017.mp4'
>   '221950562.sd.mp4 17juin2017.mp4' 
>   '222199508.sd.mp4 19juin2017.mp4'

to have only :

'11juillet2017.mp4'
'16juin2017.mp4'
'17juin2017.mp4'
'19juin2017.mp4'

the only delimiter I have in the filename is the blank after ".sd.mp4"

If some people could help me I have a directory with at least 300 files to correct.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can select all files in Finder and choose "Rename n objects..." from context menu. In the dialog choose "replace", "225086191.sd.mp4 " for the search pattern, and leave the replacement empty.

If you need to do it by terminal, you can write a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in *.mp4
do
    n=`echo $f | sed -E 's/[0-9]+\.sd\.mp4 //'`
    echo mv "$f" "$n"
done
```

Place this code as `rename-files.sh` in the directory of the mp4 files, and execute it with `sh rename-files.sh`. You can execute this without any harm, because it just prints the commands. To rename the files, you must eliminate the last `echo` command in the file (`mv "$f" "$n"`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need to replace all initial part of filename in the directory where the filename beginning with '225086191.sd.mp4 17July2017.mp4 ' or '221950562.sd.mp4 18July2017.mp4' etc.... and leave the final part of filename after the blank only, ex.: '17July2017.mp4' and 18July2017.mp4'. I'm sorry but I was not enough clear in the initial text,

Comment: You can replace the search pattern in the `sed` command with a pattern which matches better to your needs.

Comment: Yes, I would replace/rename the variable value at beginning of the filenames, before the blank, with nothing (Ex:. "225086191.sd.mp4 17July2017.mp4" will be "17July2017.mp4"). But the length of the variable part at beginning is not always the same.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen, that there different numbers in the prefix. I've adapted the pattern.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Only this : n=`echo $f | sed -E 's/[0-9]+\.sd\.mp4 //'`quote at the end of the line was omitted.